# Changing color of text followed by scope

Tags: visual-studio-code

Trying to configure VSCode to show specific foreground color for `TODO: and text that follows`

I'm trying to change the color of my `TODO: Test` to have a foreground of `#5C6370` in VSCode.

While searching for a solution I have found that editing the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` along with `textMateRules` for the specific scope (`keyword.codetag.notation.python` should possibly do the trick, but it only changes the `TODO`word , not the text that follows the word. And if I add the scope `comment.line.number-sign.python` (which is the scope of the following text) it also changes all the commenting color for my IDE.

I've also tried concatenating both scopes(`["keyword.codetag.notation.python comment.line.number-sign.python"]`), but then none of them would change colors.

Example changing only (Seen from VSCode):

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve (Seen from PyCharm IDE):

[image]

Is it possible to achieve the same result seen from PyCharm, but in VSCode? If so, how?

Comment: is the todo comment highlighting coming from an extension? have you tried using any of the todo-related extensions in the marketplace? Are you intentionally avoiding extensions to solve this problem for some reason? Are you interested in the general problem you described with highlighting a token and what follows it? Or just specifically about the case with todo comments?

Comment: @starball The TODO word highlighting is coming from the change I've done to settings.json in which I modified the scope "keyword.codetag.notation.python". I have not tried any extensions for this, I honestly didn't think someone would have created one for this type of (what it seems to be) a simple color change. And yes, I am now interested in the general problem, as to what should've been done to have the color of scope changed by whatever follows until certain point.